# How to combine two queries into one JSON file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I need to create a d3 graph. This requires a .json file as a data source.
The format of this json file is as follows

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel"},
    {"name":"Jonny"}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":2}
  ]
}
```

In order to create this I need to query two tables in my database. The easiest way to do this for formatting reasons is to actually create two queries and then join them in one json (the json file is odd as 'source' refers to the position of the node in the node array not to the database id, hence the need to do it this way). User is related to relationship as one user to many relationship.

In my model `user.rb` I have two simple queries

```
def User.allnames
    User.pluck(:name)
  end

  def User.allfollowers
    Relationship.pluck(:follower_id, :following_id)
  end
```

I would like to then combine the output from these two queries to create one json in the above format in my controller (the code below is nonsense but illustrates what I want to do:

```
def data
  #Bring in the two queries from the model
  @usersall = User.allnames
@userallfollowers = User.allfollowers

#Somehow combine them
#Then output json as below I guess

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json {  render json: @users }

      end
end
```

Comment: What 's the purpose of combining `User.pluck(:name)` and `User.pluck(:id, :name)`? First is the subset of the second one, combining them doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Good point. I have changed the question. Typo

Comment: Please mention: Is there any relationship between `User` model and `Relationship` model?

Comment: User is related to relationship as many to one. I've added to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that are saying: A user belongs to many relationships, and a relationship has many users. In that case, you can do something like that:

```
# In your controller method
@users = User.all

# other code ...

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @users.to_json( only: [:name], include: { :relationship => { only: [:follower_id, :following_id ] } }  })
end
```

Comment: OK. But the problem is that this will repeat the names in the json file according to how many relationships it has. The links between names is determined by the source and target values. The source value is determined by where the name is in the node array. Therefore the same name will have different source values and will get printed to the screen many times over with incorrect links. Hence I am looking to join two separate queries as per the question

Comment: Also I get the error syntax error, unexpected '}',expecting tASSOC